# No constructor 'Stateflow.State' with matching signature found. Error Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink, stateflow

I'm trying to create State block from `sflib` (`stateflow library`) :

```
chart = add_block('sflib/Chart', 'autoDS/Chart'); %Create Chart Block
state = Stateflow.State(chart); %Create State in Chart Block
state.Name = 'CMD_28V_Avion';
open_system('autoDS');
```

It returns me `"No constructor 'Stateflow.State' with matching signature found" error.`
How can i fix it please ? I don't know if it's a syntax or a library error as i saw on many post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_block` returns a handle to the added block (which for a state chart is actually a subsystem.)  It does not return a handle to a chart, which is what `Stateflow.State` requires as its input.  Hence the error.

You need,

```
add_block('sflib/Chart', 'autoDS/Chart'); %Create Chart Block
rt = sfroot;
m = rt.find('-isa', 'Simulink.BlockDiagram', '-and', 'Name', 'autoDS'); % block diagram
ch = m.find('-isa','Stateflow.Chart', '-and', 'Name', 'Chart'); % chart
st = Stateflow.State(ch); % state
st.Name = 'CMD_28V_Avion';
open_system('autoDS');
```

See the `Access the Model Object` and `Access the Chart Object` sections of [Create Charts by Using the Stateflow API](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stateflow/api/quick-start-for-the-stateflow-api.html)